# Biblatex with multiple categories across different refsections

Tags: biblatex

With biblatex and biber, I use  *refsections* to create multiple bibliographies. In addition I use *categories* to further split up the bibliographies. For each *refsection* I use a different bib file, which are not under my control, keys might be duplicate across different bib files.

The problem appears, when an entry is added to a category within the first refsection and another entry with the same key is added to another category in the next refsection. In the second refsection the entry is then the wrong category (as assigned within the first refsection).

Here is a running example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernums=true,doi=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{own}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{other}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}

\defbibheading{first}{\section{First Bib}}
\defbibheading{second}{\section{Second Bib}}

\newcommand{\citex}[2][own]{%
    \addtocategory{#1}{#2}%
    \cite{#2}
}

\begin{filecontents}{aaa.bib}
    @article{a,
    author = {A Author},
    title = {a from aaa.bib},
    journal = {Journal of aaa.bib}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bbb.bib}
    @article{a,
    author = {A Author},
    title = {a from bbb.bib},
    journal = {Journal of bbb.bib}}

    @article{b,
    author = {B Author},
    title = {b from bbb.bib},
    journal = {Journal of bbb.bib}}

    @article{c,
    author = {C Author},
    title = {c from bbb.bib},
    journal = {Journal of bbb.bib}}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource[label=alabel]{aaa.bib}
\addbibresource[label=blabel]{bbb.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}[alabel]
    \section{First refsection}
    First refsection with only contents of aaa.bib\citex[own]{a}
    \printbibliography[section=\therefsection,heading=first, category=own]

    Here comes the second Bibliography
    \printbibliography[section=\therefsection,heading=second,notcategory=own]

\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}[blabel]
    \section{Second refsection}
    Second refsection with only contents of bbb.bib\citex[own]{b}\citex[important]{a},\citex[other]{c}
    \printbibliography[section=\therefsection,heading=first, category=own]

    Here comes the second Bibliography
    \printbibliography[section=\therefsection,heading=second,notcategory=own]

\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

The above code results in the following [image: output]

The reference [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFyfg.png) "a from bbb.bib" is not added to the category "own" but to "important, which should be printed in the second bibliography (Section 5) instead of the first bibliography (Section 4)

The biblatex manual states

> \addtocategory{〈category〉}{〈key〉} Assigns a〈key〉to a〈category〉, to be used in conjunction with the category and notcategory filters of\printbibliography. This command may be used inthe preamble and in the document body. The〈key〉may be a single entry key or a comma-separated list of keys. **The assignment is global.**

Is there any way of keeping the categories local to the refsections?

Comment: you could probably record the assignments and clean them up at the \end{refsection}. The alternative is to use e.g. the ref section counter, so that you actually have categories `own\therefsection`  etc.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you have any idea on how to do the cleanup?

Comment: after looking at the code I don't think it will work easily, the category is written to the aux-file, and read in in the next run so it would be difficult to keep track of it. Better define refsection related categories.

Comment: hm. not so easy either. You can't define categories on the fly in the refsections. This needs some more thoughts.

Comment: At least on first glance, it's a bit odd conceptually that categories are not local to refsections: almost everything else is (or should be). I don't know whether there is a deeper reason for that, but I probably won't have time to look into that before the weekend.

Comment: I was also a bit surprised about this. But looking to manual with the problem in mind revealed the sentences **The assignment is global**. At least I think that this behaviour is meant.

Comment: Mhhh, I can't be sure about the exact intention behind that sentence, but I'd read "the assignment is global" to just mean that it is `\global` and transcends TeX groups. Most other things are not global across refsections, so it is hard to tell whether the manual really meant that. In any case the current implementation is definitely global across refsections, whether that is sensible or not.

Comment: Unrelated to the real question, but `\printbibliography` is automatically local to the current refsection, so you don't need `section=\therefsection,`. The `refsection` option is only needed if you want to print the bibliography of a different refsection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following. It adds everything to categories numbered by refsection, you can then filter with the key `refcategory`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,doi=true]{biblatex}

 \DeclareBibliographyCategory{own}
 \DeclareBibliographyCategory{other}
 \DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}


\makeatletter
\def\blx@addtocategory#1#2{%
  % If we are adding a set member to a category, make sure we also add the
  % set parent if it is cited. If it is cited, we should be using the set
  % parent in the category, not the set child member. blx@setc@... will
  % only exist if the set parent is also cited as it is only defined when a
  % member contains \inset which only happens when the set parent is cited.
  \ifcsdef{blx@setc@\the\c@refsection @#2}
    {\blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@category{#1}{\csuse{blx@setc@\the\c@refsection @#2}}}%
     \abx@aux@category{#1}{\csuse{blx@setc@\the\c@refsection @#2}}}
    {}%
  \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@category{#1}{#2}}%
  \abx@aux@category{#1}{#2}%
  %add ref categories
  \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@category{\the\c@refsection-refsection-#1}{#2}}%
  \abx@aux@category{\the\c@refsection-refsection-#1}{#2}%
  }

\define@key{blx@bib1}{refcategory}{}
\define@key{blx@bib1}{notrefcategory}{}
\define@key{blx@biblist1}{refcategory}{}
\define@key{blx@biblist1}{notrefcategory}{}
\define@key{blx@bib2}{refcategory}{\expandafter\blx@key@category\expandafter{\the\c@refsection-refsection-#1}}
\define@key{blx@biblist2}{refcategory}{\expandafter\blx@key@category\expandafter{\the\c@refsection-refsection-#1}}  
\define@key{blx@bib2}{notrefcategory}{\expandafter\blx@key@notcategory\expandafter{\the\c@refsection-refsection-#1}}
\define@key{blx@biblist2}{notrefcategory}{\expandafter\blx@key@notcategory\expandafter{\the\c@refsection-refsection-#1}}
\makeatother  

\defbibheading{first}{\section{First Bib}}
\defbibheading{second}{\section{Second Bib}}

\newcommand{\citex}[2][own]{%
    \addtocategory{#1}{#2}%
    \cite{#2}
}

\begin{filecontents}{aaa.bib}
    @article{a,
    author = {A Author},
    title = {a from aaa.bib},
    journal = {Journal of aaa.bib}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bbb.bib}
    @article{a,
    author = {A Author},
    title = {a from bbb.bib},
    journal = {Journal of bbb.bib}}

    @article{b,
    author = {B Author},
    title = {b from bbb.bib},
    journal = {Journal of bbb.bib}}

    @article{c,
    author = {C Author},
    title = {c from bbb.bib},
    journal = {Journal of bbb.bib}}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource[label=alabel]{aaa.bib}
\addbibresource[label=blabel]{bbb.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}[alabel]
    \section{First refsection}
    First refsection with only contents of aaa.bib\citex[own]{a}
    \printbibliography[section=\therefsection,heading=first, refcategory=own]

    Here comes the second Bibliography
    \printbibliography[section=\therefsection,heading=second,notrefcategory=own]

\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}[blabel]
    \section{Second refsection}
    Second refsection with only contents of bbb.bib\citex[own]{b}\citex[important]{a},\citex[other]{c}
    \printbibliography[section=\therefsection,heading=first, refcategory=own]

    Here comes the second Bibliography
    \printbibliography[section=\therefsection,heading=second,notrefcategory=own]

\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works nicely. Could you explain the solution a bit? Also, does this scale up to an arbitrary number of refsections?